# How could I write c++ construction function clean and clear?

Tags: c++, class, object

Suppose my class is like this:

```
class Strt {
    public:
        int a{0};
        int b{0};

        Strt(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
        Strt(Strt& s) {a = s.a; b = s.b;} // these two functions have same contents
        Strt(Strt&& s) {a = s.a; b = s.b;}
};
```

The problem is that the left value initialization and right value initialization is same which makes it not clean, since once I want to modify the class member variables, I need to modify the two function in the same way. The code is duplicated. How could I do it clean for better reading and maintenance ?

Edit:

There are some occasions when these construction functions are called:

```
Strt func() {return Strt(1, 2);}
vector<Strt> v;
Strt s(3, 4);
v.push_back(s); // call left construction function
v.emplace_back(func();} // call right construction function
```

There are also some occasions when modifying the class is needed, for example, when I need to add a new field of `int c;`in it:

```
class Strt {
    public:
        int a{0};
        int b{0};
        int c{0};

        Strt(int a, int b, int c): a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
        Strt(Strt& s) {a = s.a; b = s.b; c = s.c;} // The two functions are duplicatedly modified in the same way
        Strt(Strt&& s) {a = s.a; b = s.b; c = s.c;}
};
```

Must I modify the contents `Strt(Strt&)` and `Strt(Strt&&)` separately even if they have identical contents ?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Can you please list the desired usage of the constructors and their expected results?
Also, you might want to rename the class and properties to a more explanatory naming convention, it's best practice.

Comment: Useful reading: [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Gives a good run-down on when you need special copying and assigning functions and why.

Answer (score 3):

Since your class doesn't own any movable resources, there's no reason to create separate copy and move constructors.  A single copy constructor will perform identically:

```
class Strt {
public:
    int a{0};
    int b{0};

    Strt(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
    Strt(const Strt& s): a(s.a), b(s.b) {}
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4afdb2bb0eed0af)

Of course, since your copy constructor doesn't do anything but a member-wise copy anyway, you can just omit it and let the compiler generate the default one for you:

```
class Strt {
public:
    int a{0};
    int b{0};

    Strt(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2789bb7c2d77c896)

Since `a` and `b` are both public, and you don't do anything but initialize them from the constructor parameters, you can just omit your constructor entirely and use aggregate-initialization:

```
class Strt {
public:
    int a{0};
    int b{0};
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/511aea9a73ccb68c)

Comment: Hi, It seems that you only use `{}` to construct the object, what if I use `()` to construct it? do I still not need a constructor?

Comment: You have to use uniform initialization syntax (using `{}`) to do aggregate initialization.  There's a reason it's called "uniform".  Its purpose is to unify the initialization syntax of aggregates, arrays, and objects with user-defined constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Cleanest solution is to remove the user declared constructors. They are not needed:

```
class Strt {
    public:
        int a{0};
        int b{0};
};
```

Comment: Why ? Do I even need to delete the `Strt(int a, int b)` ?

Comment: You don't need to. But the class will be simpler if you do. Simpler is better.

Comment: Will this support initialization like this: `Strt s(1, 2);` if I delete that?

Comment: No, but it will allow `Strt s{1, 2};`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you might default or omit your copy/move constructor:

```
class Strt {
public:
    int a{0};
    int b{0};

    Strt(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
    Strt(const Strt&) = default;
    Strt(Strt&&) = default;
};
```

In the general case, you might use delegating [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class Strt {
public:
    int a{0};
    int b{0};

    Strt(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
    Strt(const Strt& rhs) : Strt(rhs.a, rhs.b) {}
    Strt(Strt&& rhs) : Strt(rhs) {}
};
```